# Code not outputting to the screen

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm practicing with JavaScript and p5, but when I tried to run this example on my browser locally, all I get is a black screen and the GUI. What I'm supposed to see is text being displayed via lines and some particle motion both on the screen and when I click my mouse. I double checked to make sure that the correct libraries have been included, and I re-downloaded the code from the tutorial multiple times. Right now, the only thing showing up on my screen is the GUI (and it also seems that the "message" control in the GUI doesn't work either). And just a fyi, I'm using Chrome.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
  <script src="./libraries/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="./libraries/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./libraries/rune.js"></script>
  <script src="./libraries/rune.font.js"></script>
  <script src="./libraries/rune.font.js"></script>
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
// update particles position on/off
var f;
var path;
var polys;
var drawing = false;
var gui, params;
var anchorX, anchorY;
var particles = [];

// this function loads a font, and create an array of polygons
// a polygon being itself an array of vectors with x/y coordinates
// in this example we want to create a new 'tentacle' on each point on the outline
// of the font path
function getPoints(){
    drawing = false;
    // create new font : we use rune
    console.log(params.font);
    f = new Rune.Font(params.font) 
    particles = [];
    // load the font
    f.load(function(err){       
        path = f.toPath(params.message, 0, 0, params.size)
        polys = path.toPolygons({ spacing:params.spacing })

        for (var j=0; j < polys.length ; j++){ // get each polygon
                var poly = polys[j];      
                for(var k = 0; k < poly.state.vectors.length; k++) { // get each point of each polygon
                    var vec = poly.state.vectors[k];       
                    particles.push(new Particle(random(0,windowWidth), random(0,windowHeight), vec.x,vec.y));
                }
        }
        drawing= true;
    });
}


function setup(){
    createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight)  
    background(0)

    // init all parameters
    params = new Parameters();
    // create dat.gui drawer
    gui = new dat.GUI();
    // gui setup
    var f2 = gui.addFolder('configuration / path generation');
    var f1 = gui.addFolder('real-time parameters');

    // Configuration parameters
    // font selector
    f2.add(params, 'font', {Avenir : "../fonts/AvenirNextLTW01-Medium.woff", BlackOpsOne : "../fonts/Black_Ops_One/BlackOpsOne-Regular.ttf",
                            Comfortaa : "../fonts/Comfortaa/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf",
                            NovaMono : "../fonts/Nova_Mono/NovaMono.ttf", ShadowsIntoLight : "../fonts/Shadows_Into_Light/ShadowsIntoLight.ttf", 
                            Sniglet: "../fonts/Sniglet/Sniglet-ExtraBold.ttf",Tangerine : "../fonts/Tangerine/Tangerine_Bold.ttf",
                            UnicaOne : "../fonts/Unica_One/UnicaOne-Regular.ttf"});  
    f2.add(params, 'message').listen();
    f2.add(params, 'spacing', 1, 40).listen();
    f2.add(params, 'size', 100, 1000).listen();
    f2.add(params, 'regenerate');

    f1.addColor(params, 'background').listen();
    f1.addColor(params, 'color').listen();
    f1.add(params, 'strokeWeight',0.1,2).listen();
    f1.add(params, 'threshold',10,150 ).listen();
    f1.add(params, 'show_particles').listen();
    f1.add(params, 'xoffset',0,windowWidth-300).listen();
    f1.add(params, 'yoffset',0,windowHeight).listen();

    gui.add(params, 'preset0')
    gui.add(params, 'preset1')
    gui.add(params, 'preset2')
    gui.add(params, 'preset3')

    gui.add(params, 'save')

    getPoints();
}


function draw(){
    noStroke();
    fill(params.background)
    rect(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight)

    if (drawing){

            for (var i = 0 ; i < particles.length ; i++){
                particles[i].update(); 
                 particles[i].check_bounds(); 
                if (params.show_particles)particles[i].draw();  
            }

            push()
            translate(params.xoffset, params.yoffset)
            strokeWeight(params.strokeWeight )
            stroke(params.color);

            for (var j=0; j < polys.length ; j++){ // get each polygon
                var poly = polys[j];      
                for(var k = 0; k < poly.state.vectors.length; k++) { // get each point of each polygon
                    var vec = poly.state.vectors[k];        
                    for (var i = 0 ; i < particles.length ; i++){
                        if (dist(particles[i].x-params.xoffset, particles[i].y-params.yoffset, vec.x, vec.y) < params.threshold){
                            line(particles[i].x-params.xoffset, particles[i].y-params.yoffset, vec.x, vec.y)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            pop()
    }

    if(mouseIsPressed && mouseX < windowWidth-300)  particles.push(new Particle(mouseX,mouseY,mouseX,mouseY));
}

function Particle(x,y,tx,ty){
    this.x =x ;
    this.y =y;
    this.size = 5;

    var r = random(1)
    var signe = 1
    if(r < 0.5){
        signe = -1
    }
    this.xspeed = signe * random(0.15,1.5)

    r = random(1)
    signe = 1
    if(r < 0.5){
        signe = -1
    }
    this.yspeed = signe * random(0.15,1.5)

    //this.xspeed = 0;
    //this.yspeed = 0;    

    this.xacc= 0;
    this.yacc =0;

    this.targetX = tx;
    this.targetY = ty;


    this.draw = function(){
        fill(params.color);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);        
    }

    this.update = function(){
        this.xspeed += this.xacc
        this.yspeed += this.yacc

        this.x = this.x + this.xspeed
        this.y = this.y + this.yspeed

        this.xacc = 0;
        this.yacc = 0;

    }

    this.check_bounds = function(){

        if (this.x < 0 || this.x> windowWidth){
            this.xspeed = - this.xspeed;   
        }
        else if (this.y<0 || this.y>windowHeight){
            this.yspeed = - this.yspeed;
        }

    } 
}


var Parameters = function(){

    this.font = "../fonts/AvenirNextLTW01-Medium.woff"
    this.message = 'p5*js';
    this.spacing = 20;
    this.size = 600;

    this.background = [0,0,0,150]; 
    this.color = [237,34,93];
    this.strokeWeight = 0.51;
    this.threshold = 50;

    this.xoffset = windowWidth/3 - this.size
    this.yoffset = windowHeight*2/3

    this.show_particles = true;



    this.regenerate = function(){
        background(0); 
        getPoints();
    }

    this.save = function(){
        saveCanvas()
    }

    this.clear = function(){
        background(0); 
    }

    this.preset0 = function(){
        this.spacing = 20;
        this.size = 600;
        this.background = [0,0,0,150]; 
        this.color = [237,34,93];
        this.strokeWeight = 0.51;
        this.threshold = 50;
        this.show_particles =true;
        getPoints();
    }

    this.preset1 = function(){
        this.spacing = 40;
        this.size = 600;
        this.background = [0,0,0,5]; 
        this.color = [237,34,93];
        this.strokeWeight = 0.25;
        this.threshold = 75;
         this.show_particles =false;
        getPoints();
    }

    this.preset2 = function(){
        this.spacing = 8;
        this.size = 600;
        this.background = [0,0,0]; 
        this.color = [237,34,93];
        this.strokeWeight = 0.41;
        this.threshold = 85;
         this.show_particles =false;
        getPoints();
    }

    this.preset3 = function(){
        this.spacing = 4;
        this.size = 600;
        this.background = [0,0,0,50]; 
        this.color = [237,34,93];
        this.strokeWeight = 0.41;
        this.threshold = 25;
        this.show_particles = false;
        getPoints();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check you [JavaScript console](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for errors. You could also try getting a simple example working first, and only adding a couple lines at a time to figure out what's causing the error.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Ah, now I can see the error message "failed to load rune.font.js Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." I've heard of one solution where I can setup a local websever, but would uploading this to GitHub also help solve this problem?

Comment: How are you running this code now? Is it from a local webserver, or are you just using a `file://` url? Basically step one is to run it in a webserver. GitHub pages is one option, but there are a ton of other options out there as well.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Yes, right now I'm just using the file:// url.

Comment: Okay cool, then yeah that makes sense- you'll want to host your files on a webserver.